# アップロードした写真を自動的に圧縮出来る方法があればご教授下さい。

Tags: javascript, php, java

知見のある皆様へ

昨日も投稿しましたが、誤解を与える質問かなと思いましたので再度投稿させて頂きます。

さて　現在　某顧客から申込受付システムの提案依頼・相談されております。
（業務ノウハウが弊社にあり、その点を評価されての提案依頼です）

顧客からは
・サービス申込には本人確認書（免許書・マイカード等）が必要になる。
　よって　本人確認証明書を写した画像ファイルを申込受付サイトから
　アップロードさせたい。
・本人確認書は多くの場合スマホで撮影される事を想定しているが、
　昨今　スマホのカメラ機能がアップし画像ファイルの容量が大きく
　なる傾向がある。
　一方　システムを稼動させるサーバのＨＤＤの容量を有効的に
　つかいたい。
　その為アップロードされた画像ファイルを圧縮してＨＤＤ保存しておきたい。
　（圧縮ツール使い前日申込分を手動で圧縮させる等は嫌な模様です）

上記要望が出ております。
　　　※個人的には画像ファイルを圧縮しても、劇的にファイル容量が小さくなる事はないと
　　　　思いますが。。。

要望を満たす為に、
1.申込WEB画面でファイルアップロード時に自動圧縮　サーバサイドの送信。
　　（申込WEB画面をHTML+Javascript　Or　HTML+PHP　等の組み合わせで開発？）

2.送付されてきた画像ファイルをサーバサイドで圧縮
　　（Javaを使って画像ファイルを圧縮するPGを作成。
　　　作成したPGをタイムスケジュールとかに登録して自動稼動）

上記二通りが思いつきます。

1は実現は難しいのかなと推測しております。
2に関しては、ネットで圧縮PGとしてImageIOを使った参考例として下記を見つけました。

```
public static byte[] resize(final byte[] src, final double scale) throws IOException
{
    try (ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(src);
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            BufferedImage srcImage = ImageIO.read(is);
            BufferedImage destImage = resizeImage(srcImage, scale);

            // 保存品質は「75」になる
            ImageIO.write(destImage, "jpeg", os);
            return os.toByteArray();
        }
}
```

保存品質を指定できない方法との事でしたが、本人確認書の為ですから、
それほど問題にはならないと考えております。

【ご質問】
前書きが長くなりましたが、
・1について良い方法があればご教授下さい。
・2について良いPGがあればご教授下さい。
・1・2以外の方法があればご教授下さい。

以上宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

フロントサイドの画像加工について
大きな流れとしてはJavascriptをCanvasで書き出してサイズ加工した上でbase64に書き出してblobとしてPOSTする流れでイケルと思います。

ブラウザでローカル画像をリサイズしてアップロードhttps://qiita.com/komakomako/items/8efd4184f6d7cf1363f2
詳細なプログラムはこちらを参考にしてください。

ただし、Canvasはブラウザ制約があるので一度ご確認ください。
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Canvas

Javaを利用したサーバサイドでの加工
こちらは私はちょっとわかりません。

それ以外の方法として
サーバサイドで実行するのであればimagemagicを利用することで可能です。
http://imagemagick.rulez.jp/
サーバにimagemagicをインストールしてコマンドラインで実行することになります。
ほとんどのサーバでインストールして使えると思います。

PHPはフロントサイドではなくてサーバサイドの言語になります。
PHPであれば拡張ライブラリが存在するので
http://php.net/manual/ja/book.imagick.php
こちらを利用してもいいと思います。

Comment: 有難うございました。
恥ずかしながらJAVASCRIPTに対して知見があまりないので
大変お手数ですが、もし可能であれば。
「JavascriptをCanvasで書き出してサイズ加工した上でbase64に
　書き出してblobとしてPOST」
サンプルコードとかも頂ければ幸いです
今後の勉強の参考にさせて頂きますので


また　現実的には「imagemagic」の使用が良いのかも知れません。
社内エンジニアにも連携して、提案時に盛り込めるように
してみます。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 回答中にあるように詳細なプログラムはqiitaのURLを参考にしてください。

Comment: 度々ありがとうございます。参考にさせて頂きます。